# Ruby Benign vale for nil DateTime

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, comparator, ruby-1.9, date-comparison

When comparing `DateTimes`, all objects being compared must be the same type. However, I have a data set that has `nil` dates. I want to treat these dates as older (or perhaps newer) than any other date. Is there a way to construct a benign value that will compare as older (or alternatively, newer) than any other date?

example:

```rb
data = [
  { name: :foo, timestamp: make_benign(some_valid_timestamp) },
  { name: :bar, timestamp: make_benign(nil)}
]

data.sort_by{|datum| datum[:timestamp]} #=> [<bar>, <foo>]
data.max_by {|datum| datum[:timestamp]} #=> <foo>
data.min_by {|datum| datum[:timestamp]} #=> <bar>
```

*EDIT:* I happen to be stuck on ruby 1.9 for this problem, so solutions for older versions of ruby would be nice. (But newer solutions also are nice for future reference)

Comment: How do you compare them? Why is the date required to be older? Please add more details

Comment: Does it matter why the date is required to be older? that's just what I want to do. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), the requirement is *not* that "all objects are the same type". It says:

> The other should be a date object or a numeric value as an astronomical Julian day number.

So for a benign value that is guaranteed to be before/after *any* date, you could use `-Float::INFINITY` and `Float::INFINITY` accordingly.

```
DateTime.now > Float::INFINITY  #=> false
DateTime.now > -Float::INFINITY #=> true
```

---

EDIT:

So we need a solution that works in Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2.9, huh...

Well the reason the above won't work is because of [this monkeypatch in ActiveSupport](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/3.2.9/DateTime#%3C=%3E-instance_method):

```
class DateTime
  def <=>(other)
    super other.to_datetime
  end
end
```

This is particularly problematic. Unfortunately, you may need to just use a "[very big/small number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049528/1954610)" instead...

**However**, if you're able to upgrade a little bit to **Rails 3.2.13** (or apply this [updated monkeypatch](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/688d52933a2e611175f3d41c016cf0ba71450b17) manually), where [the method signature was changed](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/3.2.13/DateTime#%3C=%3E-instance_method) to:

```
class DateTime
  def <=>(other)
    super other.kind_of?(Infinity) ? other : other.to_datetime
  end
end
```

...Then you can use [`Date::Infinity`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/date/Date/Infinity) (TIL that's a thing) instead of `Float::Infinity`, and this "fixed" version of the method now handles it correctly:

```
DateTime.now > Date::Infinity.new  #=> false
DateTime.now > -Date::Infinity.new #=> true
```

Comment: Long term support for ruby 1.9 ended in February 23, 2015; I wasn't expecting that as a requirement... If you're using an ancient ruby version, please include that information upfront.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that :). Had I been on another project I would have had to sat 1.87... so....

Comment: Cool, works with the spaceship operator too. so pretty much perfect if you have a new enough version.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what behaviour/error do you get? I don't have that version installed, so it's troublesome for me to see what's wrong.

Comment: It works with a straight date, but with active_support 3.2.9 you get "DateTime.now < Float::INFINITY #=>
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_datetime' for Infinity:Float"

Comment: Oh... Jeez... And you *also* forgot to mention that this is a Rails 3.2 project (with ActiveSupport monkeypatches)? Please try to include **all** critical information upfront.

Comment: It's quite possible, then, that there's a better solution entirely: If the data is coming from a database, then you can `order('timestamp DESC NULLS LAST')` (or `NULLS FIRST`).

Comment: Ooh, I was not aware of that SQL syntax. Nice. Sadly, not helpful here.

Comment: Yeah, so I verified it is actually the ActiveSupport monkey patches that break it. Didn't know that was relevant until I found it was broken.

Comment: `Date::Infinity` ftw :). That is what I needed.

Comment: I guess it's also worth mentioning that this ActiveSupport method changed several times over the years... You can see the latest, more reliable version (last edited in April 2016) [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dd868aa0c82ab45d1ca21febf179bb5cd1c21766/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb#L204-L210).